# Registration Form Type using 2 diferent clases

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a registration form in symfony for users, those users are related to another field of another table (cities) and I want that to login the user can choose their own city, but I cant get the registration form to add me the cities that the user selects through a drop-down list. Its really fustrating.

This is the code of the registration form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email')
        ->add('Password', PasswordType::class, [
            // instead of being set onto the object directly,
            // this is read and encoded in the controller
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                ]),
                new Length([
                    'min' => 6,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                    'max' => 4096,
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('apellidos')
        //Falta por añadir el mensaje y la ciudad
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
    ]);
}
```

And this is the code of the registration controller

```
    /**
 * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
 */
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // encode the plain password
        $user->setPassword(
            $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('Password')->getData()
            )
        );
        //El usuario empezara con 0 minutos de saldo cuando se registre
        $user->setTiempo(0);

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // do anything else you need here, like send an email

        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
    }

    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you didnt add the cities to the form. You have to add it. For this you have to choices...

1. Use the Entity itself ( EntityType )
2. Make a Custom FormType for the cities

For your knowledge, i would prefer the EntityType. Like so ... and read more about the EntityType/CustomType @documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

```
$builder
        ->add('email')
        ->add('cities', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Cities::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'choice_value' => 'id'
        ])
        ->add('Password', PasswordType::class, [
            // instead of being set onto the object directly,
            // this is read and encoded in the controller
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                ]),
                new Length([
                    'min' => 6,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                    'max' => 4096,
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('nombre')
        ->add('apellidos')
        //Falta por añadir el mensaje y la ciudad
    ;
```